The problem of equality and Hilbert space
Problem:

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space. $x_k\in H$, $a_k\in \mathbb{R} \; (k=\overline{1,n})$. Prove that
$$\sup_{\sum a_k^2\leq 1}\left \| \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k \right \|=\sup_{\left \| x \right \|\leq 1}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x,x_k)^2 \right )^{1/2}$$

My attempt to solve:
First expression
$$\sup_{\sum a_k^2\leq 1}\left \| \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k \right \|$$
is equivalent to searching for the largest value of the norm of the vector, which can be represented as a linear combination $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k $, where $a_k $ are coefficients satisfying the condition $\sum a_k^2 \leq 1$
Second expression
$$\sup_{\left \| x \right \|\leq 1}\left ( \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x,x_k)^2 \right )^{1/2}$$
This is the supremum of the norms $(x,x_k)$ for all $x$ with a norm not exceeding 1. This is the maximum value of the norm of the vector $x$ that lies on the unit sphere in the Hilbert space $H$
The right side of the equality represents the maximum length of the projection of the vector $x$ onto the space spanned by the vectors $x_k$. And the left side of the equality represents the maximum length of the linear combination $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k$, provided that the sum of the squares of the coefficients of this combination does not exceed 1. But this maximum length will be achieved by selecting the coefficients $a_k$ such that $a_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of the vector $x$ with respect to the vectors $x_k $
My question:
Did I approach the task correctly? There are some doubts, since I came to the conclusion that both sides of the equality give the same number
If not, how can this problem be proven? I've never seen such equality

Your interpretation for the two sides are correct, but it's difficult to generate a proof based on this idea -- unless $x_k$ are orthonormal, Fourier coefficients don't make much sense.
Without loss of generality, we may assume $H=\mathbb R^n$ ($H$ itself is not necessarily finite dimensional, but apparently only the subspace generated by $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ matters. Even if they are linearly dependent, we may still expand it to get an $n$-dimensional space). Let $A$ be the matrix whose $i$-th row is the vector $x_i$. Now It's easy to see the LHS is just $$\sup_{(a_i)\in H, \|(a_i)\|\le 1} \|(a_1, \cdots, a_n) A\| = \sup_{(a_i)\in H, \|(a_i)\|\le 1} \|A^t \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix} \| = \|A^t\| $$
While the RHS is $$\sup_{x\in H, \|x\|\le 1}\|Ax\|=\|A\|$$
So we are essentially asked to show $\|A^t\|=\|A\|$ for any matrix $A$. This is true because $A$ and $A^t$ are adjoint operators (or in a more concrete way).
This can be generalized to the case $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \|x_i\|^2<\infty$, then
$$\sup_{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|^2\le 1}\|\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ix_i\|=\sup_{x\in H, \|x\|\le 1}\|\sum_{i=1}^\infty (x, x_i)^2\|^{1/2}$$
The convergence and boundedness can be proved by Cauchy-Schwartz.
The equality follows similarly: Without loss of generality, assume $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, define $Ax = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x, x_i)e_i$ and then show that $$A^*(a) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ix_i$$
